# Office 2010 Shared PIA is not Available?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have an Excel Add-In for Excel-2010 version, which was created using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
The code is written in C#. To install the Add-In , you have to run a setup.exe file which will add the Add-In to Excel.
Everything seems to be working fine on Excel 2010, but when I am trying to install this on Excel-2103

I am getting the following Error:

**The Office 2010 Shared PIA System is not Available.**

Is there a way to install the add-in in the 2013 and also after it is installed will it work Perfectly or do i need to make any changes ?

Comment: The PIAs are no longer required since .NET 4 and VS2010.  Replaced by the superior Embed Interop Types feature.  Simply omit it from your install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to figure out but its done finally.
The add in launch conditions were checking for the availability of the shared PIA.

Condition: HASSHAREDPIA
and it was looking for the corresponding component id associated with excel 2013 PIA component ID

Click Here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1fd8690a-812c-49f9-a77e-e19f24de7c4e/office-2013-pia-component-ids?forum=vsto

to obtain the suitable component id and replace it in the 
**Search Target Machine** 
   *Search for office 2010 shared PIA.*
and replace the component id. 
the add in should be working fine.